# Day names not showing after Solspace Calendar upgrade

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar, upgrade, ee2-upgrades

Calendar is displaying after upgrade to latest version of EE but the day names for `{exp:calendar:cal` aren't displaying.

I get `day_1_3` as an output instead. It's the same for `{day_of_week}` as it is for `{day_of_week_short}`.

I'm using EE 2.11.1 and Calendar 1.8.14

Comment: Which version of PHP and MySQL are you using?

Comment: PHP 5.5.26 and MySQL 5.5.42

Comment: Might be better creating a support ticket instead of posting here then